# Polymorphic Join Table in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join

In my app, an Event has multiple items associated with it, potentially all of different types.  For example, a "User ate a Banana" Event would have a User and a Banana associated with it.

It seems like one way to accomplish this would be to have a polymorphic join table with 3 fields: event_id, attachable_type, and attachable_id, where attachable is the polymorphic type.

Is this possible and/or am I way off base here?

Answer (score 3):

I usually use the `has_many_polymorphs` plugin for this. On [m.onkey.org](http://m.onkey.org/) there is a [great article on that](http://m.onkey.org/has_many_polymorphs-for-dummies).

You need a join table and then could write something like this in `event.rb` for example:

```
has_many_polymorphs :items, :from => [:users, :bananas]
```

`bananas.rb` would then have something like:

```
belongs_to :event
belongs_to :item, :polymorphic => true
```

Something I tend to forget is that although banana only belongs to one event, you still will have to call `banana_instance_1.events` (notice the plural!). That's weird but works. If you call `.event` you get `nil`.